# Get multiple insert IDs from INSERT IGNORE statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to realize a tag feature for article posts, so a user can add several tags when posting an article.

I have a `tags` table, an `articles` table and a `article_tags` table.

tags:

```
id | tag (Unique)
```

articles:

```
id | title | content
```

article_tags:

```
id | article_id | tag_id
```

So (1) when a new article is to insert, I need to insert into the `articles` table and get the insert id as `article_id`.

(2) Then, I use a single `INSERT IGNORE` statement to insert multiple tags into the `tags` table. Among these tags, some may exists and will be ignored.

(3) Now I am about to insert the relations of articles and tags with `article_tags`. However, how can I get the IDs in step (2) to serve as `tag_id` in the last table?

Or I just cannot (instead, to use a one by one insert solution)?

Answer (score 1):

@AdrienXL's answer is a one-by-one solution.

I find that I can first batch insert the tags with `INSERT IGNORE`.

And when I insert the relations for `article_tags`, I can use a "batch select" query to get the IDs. So I don't necessarily need to manually fetch and store the tags' IDs in `tags` table.

The pseudo-SQLs would like:

```
INSERT IGNORE tags (tag) VALUES [the tag array]
```

And

```
INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id) 
    SELECT id, [some_article_id] FROM tags WHERE tag IN [the tag array]
```

Answer (score 0):

Model :

```
   public function insert_articles($data)
   {
      $this->db->insert('articles', $data);
      return $this->db->insert_id(); 
   }

   public function insert_tags($data)
   {
     $insert_query = $this->db->insert_string('tags', $data);
     $insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query);
     $this->db->query($insert_query);

     return $this->db->insert_id(); 
   }

   public function insert_article_tags($data)
   {
     return $this->db->insert_batch('articles_tags', $data);
   }
```

Controller :

```
   public function myfunction()
   {
     $id_article = $this->my_model->insert_articles($data);
     $article_tags = array();
     foreach($mytags as $t)
     {
         $id_tag = $this->my_model->insert_articles($data);
         array_push($article_tags, array("id_article" => $id_article, "id_tag" => $id_tag));
         //Supposed two fields table : id_article | id_tag
     }

     $this->my_model->insert_article_tags($data);
   }
```

Comment: You might misunderstand my question.